# timezone management in polars groupby_dynamic

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-polars

I am exploring `polars` and encountered an unexpected behavior (at least to me) as shown below.

```py
In [1]: import polars

In [2]: polars.__version__
Out[2]: '0.16.9'

In [3]: df = (
   ...:     polars.DataFrame(
   ...:         data={
   ...:             "timestamp": ["1970-01-01 00:00:00+01:00", "1970-01-01 01:00:00+01:00"],
   ...:             "value": [1, 1],
   ...:         }
   ...:     )
   ...:     .with_columns(
   ...:         polars.col("timestamp").str.strptime(
   ...:             polars.Datetime, fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%:z"
   ...:         )
   ...:     )
   ...:     .with_columns(
   ...:         polars.col("timestamp").dt.convert_time_zone("UTC").alias("timestamp_utc")
   ...:     )
   ...: )

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────────────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ timestamp                  ┆ value ┆ timestamp_utc           │
│ ---                        ┆ ---   ┆ ---                     │
│ datetime[μs, +01:00]       ┆ i64   ┆ datetime[μs, UTC]       │
╞════════════════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +01:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 1969-12-31 23:00:00 UTC │
│ 1970-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC │
└────────────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────┘

In [5]: df.groupby_dynamic(
   ...:     index_column="timestamp", every="1d", closed="left"
   ...: ).agg(polars.col("value").count())
Out[5]: 
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp                  ┆ value │
│ ---                        ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs, +01:00]       ┆ u32   │
╞════════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1969-12-31 01:00:00 +01:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 1970-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00 ┆ 1     │
└────────────────────────────┴───────┘

In [6]: df.groupby_dynamic(
   ...:     index_column="timestamp_utc", every="1d", closed="left"
   ...: ).agg(polars.col("value").count())
Out[6]: 
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp_utc           ┆ value │
│ ---                     ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ u32   │
╞═════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1969-12-31 00:00:00 UTC ┆ 1     │
│ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC ┆ 1     │
└─────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

The definition of the `timestamp` seems to include correctly the timezone as confirmed by the conversion to UTC.

When resampling by day, while the count is correct when dealing with the UTC timezone (column `timestamp_utc`), I think that the one with the `timestamp` column is not as it should have aggregated the two rows into `1970-01-01 00:00:00+01:00`.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly do you expect?

Comment: I would have expected `1970-01-01 00:00:00+01:00 | 2`, nothing in 1969.

Comment: ok I still don't get it ^^ I mean, your input has two date/times on the same day, and you resample to daily, in this case I'd expect either only one value (i.e. data binning) or two values on different dates (as you got in your example; although I don't know why exactly groupby_dynamic gives that result)

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear. The time series has indeed two timestamps on `1970-01-01` in the local timezone `+01:00`. When aggregating daily, I would expect that the count would be 2 on the `1970-01-01` in the local timezone as both timestamps correspond to this date in the local timezone.

Using what you said, for the local timezone, there should be one aggregated record (one value) but this is not the case.

Comment: looks like a bug, might want to open an issue on their github

Comment: I doubt this is time zone specific; it's more about the behavior of groupby_dynamic in edge cases such as if the input spans less than the specified period

Comment: It is indeed a bug, see [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7274).

Comment: looks like the fix will be available in the next release - well done @FlavienLambert for having noticed this and having lead to its resolution!